# Chat thinks I am suspended but I am not (anymore)

Tags: support, chat, account-suspension

I got suspended few days ago but the issue got soon resolved and I got my rights back.
Well, except for chat room. Today I found out that *This user is temporarily suspended and cannot chat for 3 days.*

I guess chat rooms don't take into account the possibility of prior removal of the suspension? So this is a bug in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've unsuspended you.

For the general case, however, a suspension (which is a rare event) and an early removal of the suspension (an even rarer event) are, in my view, too much of an edge case to warrant an automatic handling of this.

Some background info as to why this is non-trivial: When the user's profile is synced with the parent site, the new suspension period in chat is the larger one of the previous suspension in chat and the now-retrieved suspension on the parent site.

In your case, this was:

- previous suspension in chat: 3 days
- retrieved suspension on parent site: zero
- resulting new suspension in chat: 3 days.

The reason for this is that it is possible to suspend a user *only* on chat. So if I decide to suspend a user from chatting, but there's no reason to suspend them from participation on the parent site, it would be wrong for chat to assume the suspension can removed because 
the user is not suspended on the parent site.

Now, obviously, there can be ways to handle this, but as I said, for such a rare event, requiring the click on "unsuspend this user" on *two* sites instead of one is just fine.

Comment: I should've realized that the issue isn't as simple as I imagined it to be. So thanks, both for the unsuspension and for the explanation.

Comment: @Marek: No problem, happy chatting :)